# How to Import Azure JSON template into Visio Diagram?

Tags: json, azure, architecture, metadata, visio

I would like a process to export all the azure configurations and import them into Visio to be able to build accurate architecture diagrams of the environment.
This would allow for a 'point in time' reference for what is the current state.
Expanding on this would be the ability to have templates of diagrams to represent different perspectives of the environment ( network / server details / etc. ).
Through the use of TAGS and Metadata, you could produce the layout of platforms / applications / business aligned systems / etc.

Producing these artifacts and versioning over time will show the evolution of an environment

Eventually this feature could be incorporated completely into the portal ( export, rendering of Visio, storage of artifacts) as a service offering. consumers of the service can upload desired templates. Documents can be scheduled to be produced on intervals, on demand, or only if changes were made that day.

Comment: You're actually describing CloudockIt  https://www.cloudockit.com/

Comment: Hi there, yes I did managed to resolve the problem. I did searched online for a solution for quite sometime, with no avail, what I did, while search on www.github.com I found this opensource project https://github.com/benc-uk/azure-armviewer - by using this tool, I can download my Azure Config template in JSON then upload, the JSON file back in here for graphic visualisation.